# l have trying to send mail through django, but it got failed. I am not getting any error. But the page redirecting to the same page with different URL

Tags: python, django

> While I am sending mail through django, I am not getting any error. But the page redirecting to the same page with different URL in web page and that URL is reflecting in console also. Finally the issue is "mail not sending".
>
> > I have tried by giving permission for "Less Secure Apps".

> > Here is the code in settings.py

```
    EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT=587 
    EMAIL_HOST_USER='fhjfhfjs@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='fjsfghsfjk@123'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
```

Here is the code in views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from blog.forms import Email_Form
def mail_view(request,id):
post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=id,status='published')
sent=False
if request.method=='GET':
    form=Email_Form()
else:
    form=Email_Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd=form.cleaned_data()
        send_mail('sub','message','jfsdhfsdjk@gmail.com',[cd['to']])
        sent=True
return render(request,'blog/sharebymail.html',{'post':post,'form':form,'sent':sent})
```

Here is the code in html file

```
{%if sent%}
    <h1>Post Sent Successfully</h1>
    <h2>Post with title {{post.title}} information shared by email</h2>
{%else%}
    <h1>Share Post "{{post.title}}" By Mail</h1>
    <form>
        {{form.as_p}}
        {%csrf_token%}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg", value="Send Mail">
    </form>
{%endif%}
```

Here is the url in which the page redirecting

http://127.0.0.1:8000/4/share/?name=djfkj&email=fhsdjf%40gmail.com&to=fjshnf%40gmail.com&comments=kgjlfsgjfs&csrfmiddlewaretoken=RBXpbZW74LqvdRXdQLufO75rHmmXVMN8y9i1dN3Go9bBlpZTyEgtYEn2YGR3ZQDy

Answer (score 0):

Also set

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

in settings.py

Comment: Ok sir, Thanks for response. I'll set.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the method of the form so it is by default `get`. I assume your url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/4/share/`, so when you submit the form the inputs become get parameters and hence show up in the url. You need to specify the method as `post`:

```
{%if sent %}
    <h1>Post Sent Successfully</h1>
    <h2>Post with title {{post.title}} information shared by email</h2>
{% else %}
    <h1>Share Post "{{post.title}}" By Mail</h1>
    
    <!-- specify method below -->
    <form method="post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        {%csrf_token%}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg", value="Send Mail">
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for your reply. Now I am able send mail. It worked.